# Is there a way to change the data table pagination list?

Tags: jquery, datatable

For instance, the service I use returns 10 records per page. It also returns the number of pages and number of records. For this example, let’s assume that the page is 4 and there are 40 records.

Since my first service call only returns 10 records, the pagination at the bottom of the table will only show 1 page. Is there a way for me to change the pagination to be 1 to 4 and not 1 only?

Comment: You should return total number of records and the filtered records in response. It will automatically create the pagination buttons in bottom

Comment: The thing is, the service only returns 10 records per ajax call. Meaning, the records the initial datatable will only have 10 records. That means the data table will only show 1 page. And the trigger for me to get the next 10 records is to click the page 2 but I don’t know how to add a page 2.